# switch between file tabs in geany

Tags: shortcut-keys, geany

open some files with geany how to switch between tabs by key switch?For example you open file1 and file2 and file3 with geany . I am looking for key shortcut to switch between them I mean switch between tab. I do not like use mouse to select tabs!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for ctrl+PageUp and Ctrl+PageDown - this can also be found in Geany under Help->Keyboard Shortcuts in the notebook section

Answer (score 0):

In Lubuntu 22.04.1 I use in Geany Shift+F10 to let appear the tab-switcher. The tab-switcher is a pop-up where all open tabs are listed vertically. This is helpful when you have a lot of tabs open, and if you want to jump directly to a special tab.